# Какие файлы проекта "заливать" в СКВ(git)

Tags: git

Всем привет.
Сам вопрос в заголовке.
Мой проект:

[image: структура проекта]

Опыт работы с git уже есть, но были простые файлы. 
Тут уже использую Gulp, Bower и т.д. Папку build(собранный проект) не стоит заливать, а вот что с остальным, пока не знаю.

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [Что должно и не должно быть в .gitignore для любого языка и IDE?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/474556)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В репозитории не нужны:

- bower_components - устанавливаются с `bower install`
- build - генерируются их локальных файлов
- node_modules - `npm install`

Все остальные файлы нужны

Comment: Спасибо. Теперь все ясно)